# What does it mean when a track "straddles north"?

Tags: air-traffic-control

Have heard a couple controllers taking note of a track that "straddles north".  What do they mean?

According to Google, the definition of the verb straddle is to extend across or be situated on both sides of.  Cannot see how this would relate to a track.

Comment: Some context would probably be useful: can you add some information about where/when you heard this?

Comment: This does seem out of context. It's either missing a modifier or the missing information is implicit in the context. More typically, it would be something like _"a track straddling north Dakota and Canada"_.

Comment: Desired track is 002 degrees. Wind is from 270 (don't worry about true/magnetic for now.) A Piper Cub has a heading somewhere west of north to maintain a track of 002.  Is this the straddling you are referring to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the problem is that cruising altitudes are assigned based on heading E or W. If the desired track is within a few degrees of north or south, the heading needed to maintain the track could 'straddle' north or south. With some tracks/wind combinations two aircraft flying the identical route at different airspeeds could fall into opposite hemispheres. Traffic in the reverse direction has the same issue, possibly resulting in opposing traffic at the same altitude. So which altitude do you assign/use?